# pass Excel file from html form input to rest java method

Tags: java, angularjs, excel

I want to take excel file from html form input (input) and pass it to my rest java method and perform some operations on it. I am also using angularJs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to proccess it in your java code. Than create some json from it and post it throught rest.

You can proccess your excel with https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/.

Here is a great example how to use restful services.
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Comment: I wanted to know what exactly shouold be in my angular controller.?